# Escaping * with Regular Expressions and Grep

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression, quoting

I have a file that has unique lines that start with 2 stars (**).

However when I run a grep command for

```
grep \*\* fileName
```

I get all of the lines in the file. This is very unusual, and what I see as non-matching lines do not contain **.

How would I escape the ** for the correct lines to be found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So try :

```
egrep "^\*\*" YOUR_FILE
```

Don't forget to use double quote.

**Note:** Use `egrep` instead of `grep`.

If you want to use `grep` use `grep -E`

Comment: That was the reason why... I'm not sure why it behaved differently because I had quotes versus no qoutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, i just can say , implementation of `grep family`,such as `fgrep`, `egrep` are weak.If you want to use `regular expression`, use `awk interprreter`.

Comment: `egrep` is not standard. `grep -E` is the one you want to use if you want extended regular expressions as in `awk`. However, `^\*\*` is the same in basic regular expressions and extended regular expressions. So `grep '^\*\*'` is just as fine.

Comment: I actually use single quotes for this to work!!

Answer (score 12):

You can also achieve the same thing by instructing `grep` that the string it's to match is a fixed string. The switch to do this is `-F` or `--fixed-strings`.

```
-F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list of fixed strings, separated by 
          newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

So something like this will do it:

```
$ grep -F "**" somefile.txt
```

#### Example

```
$ cat somefile.txt
** blah
blahblah
** hi
```

Grepping the file produces this:

```
$ grep -F "**" somefile.txt
** blah
** hi
```

Answer (score 8):

In:

```
grep \*\* fileName
```

The backslashes are used to escape the `*` in the shell (where `*` is a globbing operator).

What `grep` receives as its second argument is a string of two characters: `**`.

As a regular expression, that means *any (0 or more) number of star characters*, so basically it matches everywhere since it also matches the empty string which explains why you get all the lines of the file.

Because `*` is special to `grep` regex *as well*, you need to escape it there as well. Best is to use single quotes instead of backslashes to escape `*` to the shell (because single quotes are strong shell quotes that escape every character but the single quote character itself), and use backslashes to escape `*` to grep. Double quotes would work as well in that instance, but beware that backslashes are still special to the shell inside double quotes.

So:

```
grep '\*\*' somefile.txt
```

(with `*` escaped so they're no longer regex operators but considered as literal characters) would return the lines of `somefile.txt` that contain a sequence of 2 star characters. If you want them to be found only at the beginning of the line, you've got to use the anchoring regex operator `^`:

```
grep '^\*\*' somefile.txt
```

An alternative way for `*` not to be taken as a regex operator would be to use character ranges:

```
grep '^[*][*]' somefile.txt
```

An alternative way to specify *two* star characters is to write it:

```
grep '^\*\{2\}' somefile.txt
```

(where `\{` is another regex operator) which is easier to read if you use extended regular expressions as when passing the `-E` option to `grep` (avoid `egrep` as it's not standard):

```
grep -E '^\*{2}' somefile.txt
```

(in extended regular expressions, `{` is the regex operator).