# What is the nature of grep command?

Tags: bash, grep, wildcards

I wanted to grep all the .txt files using wildcard character '*'.
I tried this command (as well as without the quotations " ") but failed.

```
ls | grep "*.txt"
```

The interesting thing is that if I put another character in the grep command corresponding to a .txt file in the directory, it works

```
>>ls | grep s*.txt
sample.txt
```

I know that `ls *.txt` will work but I was a bit amazed by the nature of the grep command. Could someone help me why is this happening?

Is it because of the fact that grep uses regular expressions, please help.

Comment: It is because it uses regular expressions, rather than wildcard (or "glob") patterns. They use many of the same symbols (like `*`), but they have different syntax and meanings.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87108/117549

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-pattern-and-regular-expression and https://askubuntu.com/questions/714503/regular-expressions-vs-filename-globbing.

Comment: you probably looking for another command like *find -maxdepth 1 -iname '\*.txt'* which searches file **names** (instead of file content)

Comment: You don't want to **grep** all the .txt files, you want to **find** all the .txt files. `grep` is for doing `g/re/p` (i.e looking for a string that matches a regexp and printing the result) **within** files while `find` is for `find`ing files (i.e. looking for files who match a given criteria including their name matching a globbing pattern). Btw - don't try to parse the output of `ls`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regexes, `*` means "any number of the previous item", not "any number of any characters", like it does in shell patterns. And `.` means "any single character".
So, to look for "anything, followed by literal `.txt`", you'd use `.*\.txt`. Or just `\.txt`, since usually regex matches search for the match anywhere in the line. Then again `\.txt` would also match a filename like `foo.txtgz`, as the `.txt` would not have to be at the end. You'd need `\.txt$` to lock the pattern to the end of line.

The regex `*.txt` is either meaningless, an error, or looks for a literal asterisk, depending on the implementation and if you're using basic regexes (`grep`), or extended regexes (`grep -E`). Best not to use it.

On the other hand, `s*.txt` would look for "any number of letters `s`, then any single character, then literal `txt`". That's a more valid regex, but... still doesn't match `sample.txt`.

Instead, what happens in your second command, is that because `s*.txt` is not quoted, the shell expands the `s*.txt` before `grep` sees it. If the only matching file is `sample.txt`, then `grep` goes looking for that in the output of `ls`. (If there were multiple matching filenames, the first would be taken as the pattern, and the rest as filenames for `grep` to read. In that case, it'd ignore the input from the pipe.)

---

But, `ls` can take a list of files too, so while you could use

```
ls | grep '\.txt'
```

to get any `.txt` file, it'd probably be easier to just use

```
ls *.txt
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is in part because `grep` uses regular expressions (in fact, that's what the `re` in the name stands for- it's short for **g**lobal **r**egular **e**xpression **p**rint).

The `*` wildcard in regular expressions is different from the `*` wildcard in shell globbing.

In regular expressions, `*` means "zero or more of the previous defined object".  However, `.` is *also* a wildcard, meaning 'one character'.

In shell globs, `*` means "zero or more characters".  `.` is not a wildcard at all.

When you `grep` for the pattern `"*.txt"`, you are looking for zero or more of anything, followed by exactly one more character, followed by the literal string `txt`.

When you `grep` for the pattern `"s*.txt"m you are looking for a literal` s`, followed by zero or more` s`s, followed by any character, followed by the literal string` txt`.

This is why one common thing you will find in regular expressions is `.*`, which means "one of any character followed by zero or more of any character".  Regexese for "literally any combination of characters other than zero characters".

When you `ls *.txt` you are telling the shell "Find any filenames that match the glob pattern `*.txt`, list them here, and provide those as arguments to the `ls` command.

Comment: Specifically, the regular expression `s*.txt` means: zero or more "s" characters, followed by *any* single character (that's what `.` means in an RE), followed by "txt".

Comment: Why `*.txt` means zero or more of anything in regex? What is the previous regex in this case?

Comment: @LRDPRDX it doesn't, a repetition character like `*` coming first in a regexp like `*.txt` is undefined behavior so YMMV with what any given tool does with it.

Comment: `*` modifies with the previous atom, turning the expected count from the implicit "exactly one" to "zero or more". So `.*` is zero or more of anything (even nothing at all), not one plus zero or more. One or more anything would be `..*` , or `.+` in ERE (`grep -E`).

Comment: Similarly, a regex starting with an asterisk does not mean "zero or more of anything", the usual rule just cannot apply there since there's nothing preceding the asterisk. Instead, e.g. `*.txt` either means to match a _literal_ asterisk (in BRE), or it's just undefined and possibly an error (in ERE). (On my GNU/Linux system, `grep -E '*.txt'` appears to act the same as `grep -E '.*.txt'`, which it can do, since the meaning is undefined. But `grep '*.txt'` requires the literal asterisk.)

Answer (score 0):

please note that grep is searching file **content** while first argument is search PATTERN and other arguments interpreted as FILES to look into

it becomes more clear to you when using `grep -H -o` flags or put your `grep` inside a script and run it with `bash -x script` to see how shell globs expanded before passed as arguments

Comment: refer to askubuntu @GordonDavisson comment which also explain that behavior